# How do I vacuum under furniture without moving it?

Tags: cleaning, home

I vacuum my carpet once a week, and I would like to vacuum under furniture (sofa, etc.) once a month instead of every six months. Is there a way to vacuum or clean under the furniture in some form or fashion?

**Tried:** I can't move the furniture, because of the configuration (a lot of stuff needs to be moved). My vacuum is an upright, and the hose isn't that long. A blower *works*, but I would rather not fill a room with dust. Lifting the furniture up and vacuuming is okay, but it's a little tedious.

Comment: Why can't you move it?

Comment: @J.Musser It takes two to lift the couch, and I live alone. Relatives help me with this.

Comment: Are there a lot of pillows on the couch? Because I often simply roll it forward until it's upside down. Vaccum under it, and roll it back. Will that not work here?

Comment: It's back is to a wall, and there's a table in front.

Comment: Move the table?

Comment: @J.Musser And the couch?

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 The table will (guessing) be lighter, so you could move that aside, roll the couch forward, and vaccum, put everything back. Not a hack tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not dead-set against moving the furniture, you could use [furniture sliders](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001WAK5UW) - on most carpets, they'll allow you to single-handed move even heavy pieces of furniture without undue effort, and can be left in place between vacuumings. That's not very hacky though, so...

**Use a leaf blower** - even [inexpensive models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BOAY2Y) can exceed 150MPH and 200CFM, creating a fast-moving air current suitable for moving dust bunnies out of hard-to-reach places.

If you don't have a leaf blower but your vacuum has a blower function, you can try that too - you probably won't get as much velocity, but for short carpets and small pieces of furniture it may suffice. Other options include air compressors and [power-washers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002Z8E52Y).

J. Musser notes that you should avoid gas-powered blowers, as the exhaust may prove dangerous in poorly-ventilated areas. Also, spilled gas can ruin your carpets.

Once you've blown out the dust, just vacuum it up as you clean the rest of the carpet.

Comment: What do you do with the dust that will inevitably blow all over the place and settle on things?

Comment: Leaf blower on one end of the couch, vacuum on the other? That should theoretically blow the dust right into the vacuum.

Comment: @MattS. Except even a powerful blower must stay pretty close to the surface it's blowing to be effective, and the vacuum on the other side wont be able to catch much.

Comment: If you're gonna go with the leafblower method, I would recommend doing that *first*, before you do the rest of your cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a "hoseless" vacuum cleaner, in other words, leaf blower, combined with vacuum cleaner. It could be quite useful to pull all the dust from under your furniture, if the hose of your usual vacuum cleaner can't "creep" under your furniture (because the furniture could have small legs).

Examples of such machines can be seen [here](http://www.toro.com/en-us/homeowner/yard-tools/blowers-vacs/Pages/Series.aspx?sid=BlowersVacs) (I suspect you don't want to use diesel ones inside your house, so I linked to electric ones :) ).